# Opening and Closing Quantity query for different product in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to set opening and closing column in PostgreSQL query for different product's individual opening and closing  where I input specific date range and my first row's opening column should be up to starting date and closing should be (opening column + column1 + column2 + column 3) in each date wise row.

*** Here is my sample database

```
Date1        Product    column1  column2   column3
01/01/2017   A          25       15        20
02/01/2017   C          10       20        20
03/01/2017   B          10       10        20
04/01/2017   C          10       10        20
05/01/2017   A          10       20        10
05/01/2017   C          5        10        20
06/01/2017   B          10       10        20
06/01/2017   A          10       10        20
06/01/2017   C          10       10        20
```

My expected query in PostgreSQL * date range is 04/01/2017 to 06/01/2017:

```
Date1         Product      opening  column1  column2  column3 closing
04/01/2017    C            50       10       10       20      90
05/01/2017    A            60       10       20       10      100
              C            90       5        10       20      125
06/01/2017    A            100      10       10       20      140
              B            40       10       10       20      80
              C            125      10       10       20      165
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far? You need to post your code so that we can help - we won't write code for you.

Comment: Please see my Previous question Tittle "Opening and Closing Quantity query in postgresql" and i use the "S-Man" answered code.

Comment: You need to make *this* question complete, which means you need to show the code you have written.

Comment: SELECT
    "date1",
    product,
    closing - day_value as opening, 
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    closing
FROM (
    SELECT 
         *, 
         column1 + column2 + column3 as day_value,
         SUM(column1 + column2 + column3) OVER (ORDER BY "date") AS closing
    FROM testdata
) s


SELECT * FROM (
    -- <QUERY ABOVE>
) s
WHERE date1 BETWEEN '2017-01-03' AND '2017-01-06'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion but this is in SQL server, i'm not acquainted with Postresql.
You can run following query by passing date range in it as @trans_date by any loop or cursor whichever is suitable for u-

SELECT Date1, Product, SUM(opening.opn_qty) AS opening, SUM(column1) AS column1, SUM(column2) AS column2, SUM(column3) AS column3, SUM(closing.cls_qty) AS closing
FROM sample_table1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT(SUM(column1) + SUM(column2) + SUM(column3)) AS opn_qty,
          Product
    FROM sample_table1
    WHERE Date1 < @trans_date
    GROUP BY Product,
             Date1
) opening ON opening.Product = sample_table1.Product
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT(SUM(column1) + SUM(column2) + SUM(column3)) AS cls_qty,
          Product
    FROM sample_table1
    WHERE Date1 <= @trans_date
    GROUP BY Product,
             Date1
) closing ON opening.Product = sample_table1.catalog_item_id
WHERE sample_table1.Date1 = @trans_date
GROUP BY sample_table1.Product,
         Date1
ORDER BY Date1 DESC;

Similar logic you can apply in PostgreSQL.